# Displaying appbar above alert dialog in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am building a flutter web app. For my login page, i have a dialog that can not be dismissed until the user is logged in successfully. On my app bar, i have general information that could be valuable to the anonymous user. The problem is, the dialog overlays the entire page. Is there a way i can set my app bar above the alert dialog?

Comment: No there isn't and if there was it would be really really messy.

Comment: You can set `insetPadding` of the dialog to give more space below it, so the app bar  will be visible, although it will be masked with opacity. If you need normal view, don't use dialog.

Comment: I actually not sure, but the dialog shows on top of the Navigator of your widget tree, setting another custom Navigator widget and show the dialog on top of it could make the appbar shows on top of it.